# How to fix InflateException Error inflating class fragment when I use databinding

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment, android-databinding

I am new in kotlin & android (just to prevent).

I work on a project that is structured as OneSingleActivity.

The problem is that when I press the HOME button and then I try to go again in the app, it crashes automatically.

It gives following error code

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML
>   file line #30: Error inflating class fragment

where the source error target my line that contains the binding initializer.

My goal is to when I press on the HomeButton, and later I go in the app that stayed on the Background, retrieve the last fragment where I was.

I already tried to :

- Change manifest.xml (singleInstance, taskreparenting, clearTaskOnLaunch)
- Change the intent flag to clearTop
- Use the `DataindUtil.inflate`
- change how works the HOME button
- kill the activity when I am `onStop` (it work, but when I re launch the app, I am not on the last fragment where I was before press the HB)
- unbind

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     ...
     // Creating a binding to activity layout
     // This is where app crash
        val binding: ActivityNavigationBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_navigation)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
}
```

Fragment used in my activity_navigation.xml :

```xml
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/nav_fragment"
      android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:defaultNavHost="true"
      app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_app"/>
```

**Expected :**

- When I press HB, and go to the app in BG, app does not crash, and i am on the last fragment where I was.

**Actually :**

- App crash when I press on HB, and launch again the App that was in BG (does not works too when I click on the app's icon)

Thank all for helping a new user of kotlin & android.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like an issue with your navGraph. Check if you have specified the correct fragment names etc.

Comment: It is. The fist time when i launch the app, the fragment is correctly inflated, but when i press HB, then reload the app, that's a crash.

Comment: Ok, I strongly suspect it is your fragment which is failing to inflate. You will need to isolate the reason for crash. To verify this assumption, remove the navigation fragment from your main activity and directly add the first fragment from your navgraph to this activity's layout. If it still crashes (with android navigation), the problem is with your fragment inflation and not navigation graph.